# How to start a program alongside x11?

Tags: kde

I use KDE plasma as my desktop. And I use lattedock for my panel and dock. It is working fine but the problem is it starts a littlebit slow after all the desktop is rendered.
there are files on my desktop. In startup they will be located uptop but after latte dock starts the nofification also shifts from center to the right and the files also shift a little bit down.
It feels clunky whenever I start my desktop. But after everything loadsup it is fine. Isn't there a way to start latte dock while the xstart is doing its own thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know lattedock, but it depends heavily on KDE functionality to be available as it starts.

So, no, starting it in parallel to KDE can't really work. If needs KDE to be started.

Comment: So I have no options!

Comment: Well, I'd assume the KDE bugtracker would either already contain a bug report or would very much welcome one from your side describing the behaviour you see as undesirable. The authors might come up with a better way of integrating it more early in the KDE initialization, after KDE started the necessary services for it. It's just that you can't start it before or simultaneously with KDE.

Comment: @RosanPaudel if you are using a systemd based  distro then the lattedock should run as a systemd service generated by `systemd-xdg-autostart-generator`. You can edit the service by using `systemctl --user edit app-org.kde.latte\\x2ddock@autostart.service` for lattedock  but I don't think  it's possible to achieve what you want. (The lattedock service is located in: `/run/user/1000/systemd/generator.late`)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon yeah I am using systemd based distro. Actually its EndeavourOS. I think there is no other options beside waiting for some alternatives from the maintainer itself.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yeah I think so.